# React native image draggable crop

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I need image draggable cropping (namely with custom aspect ratio). I tried using https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor package, but cropping option was not included in Android platform. I need the same feature to have for both platforms, so I can't use that package.

Can anyone help me to find a proper solution to this please?

Answer (score 1):

I found a package which provides the feature I was searching for. It is not such a popular package, but it is good :) 
https://github.com/zainozzaini/react-native-android-image-cropper

Comment: @Vignes for IOS I use https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor, and for Android https://github.com/zainozzaini/react-native-android-image-cropper